# Best seller collection filter magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, best-seller

I am trying to filter Best seller product collection like below.

Seems the setOrder is not working.

```
  class BestSeller extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
  {
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;   
    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
     array $data = []
   ) { 
     $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
     $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;           
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }
  public function getBestSellerData(){      
    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                ->setPeriod('day') //you can add period daily,yearly      
                ->setOrder('id', 'desc')
                ->setPageSize(8);  
    return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;

}
```

This is not filtering the best seller by id with descending order. Can anyone help me on this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 public function getBestSellerData(){      
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
      $objectManager1 = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $productCollection = $objectManager1->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory');
            $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection')->setPeriod('day');
            $bestSellerProdcutCollection->load();
         $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->group('sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id')->order('sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id DESC');
        return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;

    }
```